# Cannot get local Kubernetes (minikube) to pull from local Docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, minikube

I'm feeling pretty stupid here. I want K8s to pull Docker images from a local registry to ensure my development cycle is as fast as possible.

I have set up the local registry per [the instructions](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) and am using an insecure registry. I have pushed images to it, and have confirmed they reside in the registry by looking inside it using VS Code's Docker extension:

[image: Docker images]

I didn't really know whether to use `localhost`, `$MACHINE_NAME`, or `$LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS`, so I did all three.

I can successfully pull an image from these registries via the command line. However, when K8s (running via minikube) attempts to pull, it fails:

> Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/service1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused

**Why is this and how can I rectify?**

Comment: instead of using `localhost` you have to use the ip address that map minikube to host machine's localhost. This is generally `10.0.2.2` or `10.0.2.15` based on your vm driver. You can determine using running `ifconfig` inside minikube and check ip in form of  `10.0.2.*`  This github issue might help: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2735

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read this blog which provides excellent details on how to set up registry on minikube.

https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615/

> The idea here is for the docker daemon on minikube to be able to pull from a registry called localhost:5000. This is achieved by actually running a registry on minikube and then setting up a proxy so that the minikube VM port 5000 maps to the registry’s 5000.